# How does Kahuna do 'ghost push' for apple iOS devices?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Apparently Kahuna has this magical feature:
·       Kahuna has this magical "ghost push" feature that tracks how many people uninstall or opt out of push notifications relative to any message in any campaign. You can see if you're bugging your users too much.

How does Kahuna do this?

Answer (score 0):

The name "ghost push" seems to imply the sending of a notification without knowing whether the intended app is still installed. Apple Push Notification service has a [feedback service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3) that "give you information about failed remote notifications." This is likely what Kahuna uses to track user uninstalls and opt-outs.